# webkit-region-break-inside dosn't work inside a table row / How suits long text on 2 pages always?

Tags: webkit, report, odoo, qweb

I want to print an *odoo qweb* report with long product descriptions.
If the  description doesn't fit on the first page, the description will be printed on the next page. This depends on the length of the product description.

Short descriptions always start at page one, too long descriptions for page one start on page two, but then again extreme long descriptions start at page one and are broken automatically and have a proper page break.

How can I change an odoo standard qweb report, so that the description always starts on page one.

Adding `webkit-region-break-inside` to the `table`, the `tr`, the `td` or a `p` tag inside the `td` tag didn't solve the problem.